# react + typescript function parameter hint error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

> > https://playcode.io/1001045

[image]

> > https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-varahamihira-8zq27w?file=/src/App.tsx

Which package version is this problematic?

The function parameter type can be prompted normally

Comment: It's expecting a parameter which you defined as `aaaaa`

Comment: that's interesting